# DropDownListFor in Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I have a sample application in Asp.Net MVC 4.  I don't find the way to obtain the selected id from the DropDownListFor helper and assign it as parameter to an ActionLink.

Here is my models:

```
public class EmpresaLibroViewModel
{
    //property a usar en vista Index ya que son iterables
    public IEnumerable<EmpresaModel> Empresas { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BancoModel> Bancos { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LibroModel> Libros { get; set; }

    //property que van a contener solo un registro (para Detalles, Editar)
    public EmpresaModel Empresa { get; set; }
    public BancoModel Banco { get; set; }
    public LibroModel Libro { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Edit method where I want to obtain the selected Banco ID and send as parameter to the ActionLink:

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.EmpresaLibroViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{


   @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>EmpresaModel</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Empresa.EmpresaModelID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Empresa.Nombre)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Empresa.Nombre)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Empresa.Nombre)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Empresa.Cuit)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Empresa.Cuit)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Empresa.Cuit)
    </div>

    <h3>Tiene libros en:</h3>
    <table>
            @foreach (var unitem in Model.Libros)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @unitem.Bancos.Nombre (empresa:@unitem.EmpresaModelID - banco:@unitem.BancoModelID)
                    @Html.ActionLink("(eliminar)", "DesvincularBanco", new { id = unitem.LibroModelID, idEmp = unitem.EmpresaModelID })
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
    </table>
    <h3>Agregar:</h3>
    @Html.DropDownListFor( model => model.Banco.BancoModelID , new SelectList(Model.Bancos, "BancoModelID", "Nombre")))
    @Html.ActionLink("(agregarlo)", "VincularBanco", new { idempresa=Model.Empresa.EmpresaModelID , idbanco=10 }  )

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

What is the best way to do it?
Thanks.

Note: the idBanco=10 has set to verify that working the ActionLink. I know that that value must be from the DropDownListfor.

Comment: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of jquery you can do it easily.

First, add an id to your actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("RegisterModules", "Home", new { idempresa =5, idbanco = 10 }, new { id = "myLink" })
```

Now add the script to your view ( I would prefer adding it to a javascript file and bundle the file and add to this page) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select[id*="Banco"]').change(function () {
            var lnk = $('#myLink').attr('href');
            var givenval = $('select[id*="Banco"]').val();
            var result = lnk.split("idbanco=")

            if (result.length > 1) {
                lnk = result[0] + "idbanco=" + givenval;
            }

            $('#myLink').attr('href', lnk);
        });

    });
</script>
```

And make sure that jquery is added to this page. And you are done!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is possible without javascript?

Comment: You have to change value in the client side.  Sorry, I don't think you have any choice unless you want to post the form(in that case in the posted model you will find selected value).

Comment: Ok, the unique option in that scenary is post the form or use javascript to know the selected option in DropDownListFor?

Comment: In your code you are using `<input type="submit" value="Save" />` to post the form, which is normal. I would not suggest to change it. For redirecting or any client side operation, using javascript, jquery and ajax is normal in MVC.